# SQL query in ORACLE - select most recent date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, analytic-functions

I am a newbie in the world of SQL query.
I need to eliminate the duplicate Staff # and retrieve only the highlighted row.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Staff#      Pay_DT      Due_DT      loan_flag   housing 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
123-45-6789     14-Feb-14   3-Jan-14    Y       null 
123-45-6789     14-Feb-14   3-Jan-14    Y       Annual 
123-45-6789     14-Feb-14   13-Jan-14   Y       null 
**123-45-6789   14-Feb-14   13-Jan-14   Y       Annual** 
123-45-6789     null        null        Y       null 
123-45-6789     null        null        Y       Annual
```

Comment: Why that row?  Your subject talks about the "most recent date".  You don't say which date that is.  There are 4 rows with the same maximum `pay_dt`.  There are two rows with the same maximum `pay_dt` and `due_dt`.  Why do you pick one over the other?

Comment: you want to return just  that one row?

Comment: This is a historical data. I need to know the Pay DT on which the the housing was set as annual and the payment was made. Thank you for your prompt responses.

Comment: @ Coffee - Yes. That row is the desired result.

Comment: Hey, side note. You seem to be using SSN's as identifiers in your database. I'd suggest you change that ASAP, it's a big and expensive deal if you lose them.  And it's less efficient because you need to use strings instead of numbers as identifiers.  Generally not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               rank() over (partition by staff# order by pay_dt desc) rnk
          FROM table_name a
         WHERE housing = 'Annual')
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Alternately

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               max(pay_dt) over (partition by staff#) max_pay_dt
          FROM table_name a
         WHERE housing = 'Annual')
 WHERE pay_dt = max_pay_dt
```

If you can have ties (two rows with the same `pay_dt` where the `housing` column has a value of `Annual` for a particular `Staff#` value, both of these queries would return all the rows with that condition.  If you want to break the tie arbitrarily, you could use `row_number` rather than `rank`.  Otherwise, you'd need to tell us what logic you'd want to use to break the ties.